# Shorten long name by replacing part of it with a hash code

Tags: java, string

I have a long name, and I want it to shorten up to 80 characters.

> org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils#abbreviate

function does this, but it just shorten name and append "..." at the end. 
But it would be better to shorten the name by replacing parts of it with a hash code.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: [StringUtils.abbreviate(String str, String abbrevMarker, int maxWidth)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#abbreviate-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-) ? This one lets you specify what you put instead of the ellipsis. You might want to wrap the hash generation + abbreviation in a single function of course.

Comment: If your strings truly are **names**, abbreviating them in any way could result in **more than one name**  with the **same abbreviation**.  Are you sure you can tolerate that possibility?